# How to write a docker file that actually prints something?

Tags: docker

I have a simple Dockerfile like this

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN echo "==============from docker UBUNTU 18.04"
```

Then I build the image with `docker build -t "test" .`, and run the image with `docker run -it "test"`. But the latter does not print the message above but goes to a Linux prompt. Why is the message not printed?

```
try_docker % docker build  -t "test" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> c090eaba6b94
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "==============from docker UBUNTU 18.04"
 ---> Running in 97a17d71e6bf
==============from docker UBUNTU 18.04
Removing intermediate container 97a17d71e6bf
 ---> 007cf77550ee
Successfully built 007cf77550ee
Successfully tagged test:latest
(base) zhfu@mac610881 try_docker % docker run -it "test"
root@7ae12dfc4ee9:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN` directive is executed during the docker **build** phase, as you've seen. One way to get this echo to run when you run the docker is to place it in the `ENTRYPOINT` directive:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENTRYPOINT echo "==============from docker UBUNTU 18.04"
```